# Any way to signal an end-of-file without creating a new line in command line/bash?

Tags: file, command-line

I am writing a quick little C program to count up the number of words entered via standard input and give a count of the words entered as well as the average words per line. The following code works fine for files, but when entering input into the command line, I can (seemingly) only signal an EOF (Ctrl-Z since I'm on Windows) on a new line, which throws off the line count. Is there any way to remedy this? Here are some examples:

The program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int lines = 0, totalCount = 0;
    float average = 0.0;
    char newline= ' ';

    // scanf and throw away the string values
    while (scanf("%*s%c", &newline) != EOF)
    {
        // at least one line exists
        if (totalCount == 0)
        {
            lines++;
        }

        // update count
        totalCount++;

        // account for any subsequent lines
        if (newline == '\n')
        {
            lines++;
        }
    }

    average = (float) totalCount / lines;

    printf("%d ", totalCount);
    printf("%.2f\n", average);
}
```

This works fine (the file has 313 words and 35 lines):

> a.exe < testfile.txt
>
> 313  8.94

This does not, however:

> a.exe
>
> This is a test
>
> to see if this
>
> works
>
> okay
>
> ^Z
>
> 10 2.00

The end of file adds one line to make 5 lines in total, making the average words per line come out to 2.00. Is there any way to remedy this or is that just the way it has to be?

Answer (score 0):

An update for anyone else looking for this solution:

On the Linux/Unix shell, one can enter the EOF twice on the same line to flush the line buffer and create and EOF on the same line as such:

> This is my text and now I will flush the buffer and signal EOF on the same line ^D^D

However, this method does not seem to work on the Windows command line, so I am still searching there. I will edit if I get an update.

EDIT: Using the method above throws off the input if you do not add a space in between the last character of the line and the EOF sentinel.